# Can I un-dynamicize a linked executable given a dynamic library?

Tags: shared-libraries, static-linking, dynamic-linking, dynamic-loading

Suppose I have a dynamically-linked executable which depends on symbols in libfoo and libbar; and that it works on my system, i.e. it finds appropriate versions of these shared libraries. Now, I want to "replace" the dynamic dependencies on libfoo with compiled code from the libfoo I have on my system, obtaining a new executable which only dynamically depends on libbar.

Is this possible? At least, on a modern(ish) Linux system?

If it helps, you may assume additionally that the executable results from a single C source file; that I have this file; that I compiled with/without debug info or with whatever compilation switch you like.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible?

No. Modifying linked `a.out` or `libfoo.so` is impossible for all practical purposes.

You might have some luck with the [statifier](https://statifier.sourceforge.net/), but that doesn't always work and creates huge binaries.